# How to get camera angle (FOV) on windows phone 8?

Tags: camera, augmented-reality

I'm developing an augmented reality app for wp8 and need to know the camera fov to combine 3d rendered models and camera stream accurately considering distance. Does anybody know how to get camera fov programmatically or even get any hardware camera information, i.e. size of sensor and focal length?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain your camera FOV, you can calibrate your camera to find its intrinsic parameters (focal length, principal point, skew factor and optionally distortion parameters, etc.).

Popular library to do so is OpenCV:

[OpenCV Calibration example](http://www.technolabsz.com/2012/07/camera-calibration-using-opencv.html)

Take some screenshots with you camera phone (preferably at the same resolution of your camera preview mode) and import this dataset on your PC to run the calibration process on it.

Google or look on stackoverflow about additional tutorials on the topic, keywords: camera calibration, opencv.

After there is a simple formula to convert from focal length to FOV (pinhole camera model).
To get a better precision for your AR application, it will be better to convert this perspective matrix (intrinsic parameters) from OpenCV format to an OpenGL perspective format (or DirectX). Only using the FOV will introduce errors during your registration (e.g. ideal center vs measured principal point, skew factor, etc.).